# How does java know the type of a lambda parameter?

Tags: java, lambda

In an example code like this, my IDE changed my code from using an anonymous class to return a lambda. That's cool but how does it work?

```
public static Specification<User> getUsersByFirstNameSpec(String name) {
        return new Specification<User>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<User> root,
                                         CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                         CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Predicate equalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(
                        criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("firstName")),
                        name.toUpperCase());
                return equalPredicate;
            }
        };
    }
```

How does java know the type of the 3 parameters?

```
 public static Specification<User> getUsersByLastNameSpec(String name) {
        return (Specification<User>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Predicate equalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(
                    criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get("lastName")),
                    name.toUpperCase());
            return equalPredicate;
        };
    }
```

Comment: [Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java, lambdas are interpreted in terms of a so-called 'functional interface'.

A functional interface is any interface (as in, `public interface SomeInterface { ... }`) which contains precisely 1 'non-Object, non-defaulted' method. So, for each method declared in the interface, disregard it if it is either just repeating something that's already in the spec of `java.lang.Object` itself (such as, for example, the toString in `interface Example { String toString(); }`), or which has a default impl, such as the foo in `interface Example { default String foo() { return ""; } }`. Then, how many methods are left? If the answer is precisely 1 (not 0, not 2), then it is a functional interface.

If you use a lambda (the arrow notation thing, or the `typeOrReferenceExpr::someMethod` syntax), then the place where you use it MUST be a place where the compiler can figure out precisely which functional interface is intended. If you can't, it's a compiler error. For example:

```
Object o = () -> System.out.println("Hello!");
```

this is a compile-time error. But this:

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello!");
```

is fine; `java.lang.Runnable` is a functional interface, because it has only 1 relevant method, namely `void run();`.

Once the functional interface is clear, the lambda is interpreted as being an implementation of that one method. So, in your example, java knows the types for `root`, `query`, and `criteriaBuilder` because the compiler can figure out that this is an impl of the interface `Specification<User>`, and that interface has only one (non-Object, non-defaulted) method, whose spec is:

```
Predicate toPredicate(Root<User>, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder)
```

and that's how java knows. It also figures out any `throws` clause from this, too, and the return type too.